# AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'reindex'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, generator

I'm building an event-driven, back-testing module, using Quant Start's [tutorial](http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Event-Driven-Backtesting-with-Python-Part-III) as a rough guideline, and am coming up with an interesting error.

My error occurs at the end of self._convert_csv_files()

I'm trying to reindex each dataframe in self.symbol_data to reflect the union of each dataframe's index, creating a generator object in the process.

The following code is my class:

```
class HistoricCSVDataHandler(DataHandler):
    """
    HistoricCSVDataHandler is designed to read CSV files for each requested
    symbol from a disk and provide an interface to obtain the "latest" bar in a
    manner identical to a live trading interface.
    """

    def __init__(self, events, csv_dir, symbol_list, start_date, end_date):
        """
        Initialises the historic data handler by requesting the location of the
        CSV files and a list of symbols.

        It would be assumed that all files are of the form 'symbol.csv,' where
        symbol is a string in the list.

        Parameters:
        events - The Event queue.
        csv_dir - Absolute directory path to the csv files.
        symbol_list - A list of symbol strings.
        start_date - A datetime to which we will set the start of the bar index
        end_date - A datetime to which we will set the end of the bar index
        """

        self.events = events
        self.csv_dir = csv_dir
        self.symbol_list = symbol_list
        self.bar_index = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date)

        self.symbol_data = {}
        self.latest_symbol_data = {}
        self.calls = {}
        self.puts = {}

        self.continue_backtest= True

        self._open_convert_csv_files()

    def _open_convert_csv_files(self):
        """
        Opens the CSV files from the data directory, converting them into
        pandas DataFrames within a symbol dictionary.

        For this handler it will be assumed that the date is taken from DTN
        IQFeed.  Thus, its format will be respected.
        """

        comb_index = None

        for s in self.symbol_list:
            # print "Parsing: %s" % s
            # Load the CSV file with no header information, indexed on date
            self.symbol_data[s] = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
                                    os.path.join(self.csv_dir,'%s.csv' % s),
                                    header=0, index_col=0,
                                    names=['open',
                                           'high',
                                           'low',
                                           'close',
                                           'volume',
                                           'adj close'
                                          ],
                                    parse_dates=True
                                    ).sort()

            # Combine the index and pad forward values
            if comb_index is None:
                comb_index = self.symbol_data[s].index
            else:
                comb_index = comb_index.union(self.symbol_data[s].index)

            #  Set the latest sybmol_data to None
            self.latest_symbol_data[s] = []

        self.bar_index = self.bar_index.intersection(comb_index)

        self.calls, self.puts = trades.parse_trades()

        # Reindex the DataFrames
        for s in self.symbol_list:
            #   print "Reindexing: %s" % s
            self.symbol_data[s] = self.symbol_data[s].reindex(
                                    index=bar_index, method='pad'
                                    ).iterrows()
```

The following is my traceback after %paste:

```
In [1]: %paste
# backtest.py
import dateutil.rrule as dr
import dateutil.parser as dp
import dateutil.relativedelta as drel
import pandas as pd
import csv
import Queue
import datetime
import cg

# Import Backtesting Classes
from event import MarketEvent, SignalEvent, OrderEvent, FillEvent
from data import HistoricCSVDataHandler

# Set input file
csv_symbol_list = "symbols.csv"
# Create symbol list
symbols = []
symbols_with_currency = []
symbols_with_currency = cg.create_symbols_list(csv_symbol_list)
for i in symbols_with_currency:
    symbols.append(i[0])

# Amount of total portfolio reserved for cash
percent_cash = 0.30

# Declare parameters
events = Queue.Queue()
path = "/Users/XXX/Documents/repos/cg2/data"
start_date = datetime.datetime(2010,12,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2013,12,31)

# Declare the components with respective parameters
bars = HistoricCSVDataHandler(events, path, symbols, start_date, end_date)

## -- End pasted text --
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4859f3953713> in <module>()
     35 
     36 # Declare the components with respective parameters
---> 37 bars = HistoricCSVDataHandler(events, path, symbols, start_date, end_date)

/Users/XXX/Documents/repos/cg2/data.py in __init__(self, events, csv_dir, symbol_list, start_date, end_date)
     81         self.continue_backtest= True
     82 
---> 83         self._open_convert_csv_files()
     84 
     85     def _open_convert_csv_files(self):

/Users/XXX/Documents/repos/cg2/data.py in _open_convert_csv_files(self)
    126         for s in self.symbol_list:
    127             #   print "Reindexing: %s" % s
--> 128             self.symbol_data[s] = self.symbol_data[s].reindex(
    129                                     index=self.bar_index, method='pad'
    130                                     ).iterrows()

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'reindex'
```

If I comment out the troubled for statement:

```
''' 
        # Reindex the DataFrames
        for s in self.symbol_list:
            #   print "Reindexing: %s" % s
            self.symbol_data[s] = self.symbol_data[s].reindex(
                                    index=self.bar_index, method='pad'
                                    ).iterrows()
        '''
```

I can examine the types of each component used:

```
In [5]: type(bars.symbol_list)
Out[5]: list

In [6]: type(bars.symbol_data['A'])
Out[6]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [7]: type(bars.bar_index)
Out[7]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex

In [8]: type(bars.symbol_data['A'].index)
Out[8]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

Comment: Do you have duplicates in `symbol_list`? The line causing the error is replacing the dataframes with generator objects, so if it's called twice on any symbol, you'll get the shown error. Why not just iterate over `symbol_data` instead?

Comment: The list had duplicates.  How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: I added the following code to backtest.py to remove duplicates from any symbols.csv file: `symbols = list(set(symbols))`